# Installing Resin Web Server for Java Application Deployment on Linux

Tags: java, resin

I'm seeking guidance on Resin web server and its installation process on a Linux system. My aim is to develop a Java application and deploy it using this particular server. Could someone provide guidance or step-by-step instructions on how to install Resin on Linux and subsequently configure it to host a Java application? Any insights, tips, or resources on this process would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you had a look at the official documentation? It's well, https://caucho.com/products/resin/doc